# Probability of knowing the answer conditional on picking the correct one

Tags: probability

> A student takes a multiple choice exam in which each question has $5$ possible answers. The student knows the answer to $70\%$ of all questions. If he doesn't know the answer to any question, he guesses it randomly.
>
> **(i)** What is the probability that the student chooses the correct answer for a given question?
>
> **(ii)** If the student chooses the correct answer for a given question, what is the probability that he knew the answer?

In my solution I'm unsure about part **(ii)**. **My solution:**

Let us define some events. $$S := \text{The student knows the answer}. $$

$$ S^{c} := \text{The student does not know the answer}. $$

$$A := \text{The students chooses the right answer.} $$

Then,

$$ P(S) = 70\% $$

$$ P(S^{c}) = 30\% $$

Part **(i)** asks us to find $P(A)$. That is the probability of knowing the answer $+$ the probability of guessing the correct answer.

$$ P(A) = 70\% + \Bigl( \frac{1}{5} \Bigr) 30\% = 76\% $$

Part **(ii)** asks us to find $P(A|S)$. By the definition of conditional probability,

$$ P(A|S) = \frac{P(A \cap S)}{P(S)} $$

$ P(A \cap S) \neq P(A)P(S) $ as $A$ and $S$ are not independent. So the "difficult" part is finding $ P(A \cap S) $. **My attempt:**

$$ P(A \cap S) = 1 - P(A \cap S)^c  $$

$$ (A \cap S)^c = \{x : x \notin A ~and~ x \notin S\} = A^c \cup S^c $$

$$ P(A^c \cup S^c) = P(A^c) + P(S^c) = 24\% + 30\% = 54\% $$

Therefore

$$ P(A \cap S) = 1 - P(A \cap S)^c = 1 - P(A^c \cup S^c) = 1 - 0.54 = .46 = 46\% $$

Finally

$$ P(A|S) = \frac{46\%}{70\%} = \frac{46}{70} = \frac{23}{35} $$

Comment: $P(A^c \cup S^c) \not= P(A^c)+P(S^c)$.  They aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @BrianTung that was my suspicion but at the same time I couldn't come up with anything else. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, you're using the wrong terminology, aren't you?  You want $P(S \mid A)$, not $P(A \mid S)$, right?  Then realize that $S \subseteq A$, since whenever the student knows the answer, they always answer correctly (but not *vice versa*).  So then $P(S \mid A) = \frac{P(S \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(S)}{P(A)}$.

Comment: Wow.. can't believe I spent so much time trying to answer the wrong question. I should have paid more attention. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes theorem gives the answer:
$$
P(S|A) = \frac{P(A|S)P(S)}{P(A|S)P(S)+P(A|S^c)P(S^c)}=\frac{1*0.7}{1*0.7 + 0.2*0.3}=.921
$$